# Powershell import registry key in code

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm looking to import the below registry key without actually importing the .reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cirrato]
"postInstallExecTimeout"=dword:0000001e
"ConfigApplyAllSettingsForModels"=""
"ConfigApplyAllSettingsForQueueNames"=""
"ConfigApplyPreferencesOnlyForQueueNames"=""
"OURestrictFailureCaption"=""
"OURestrictFailureText"=""
```

Is it possible to import this key in-line?  I can't find any resources demonstrating how to add a registry key with multiple values like this.

Comment: Umm... why? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Crude method would be to store the reg settings in a 'here' string, then write them to a temporary file at execution time and shell to 'regedit' or 'reg' to do the import.

Comment: I need to create this key as an SCCM configuration item, which means I can't import any files.  It must be done entirely through the script.

Comment: So you don't actually have that .reg file, but want to create the same settings as importing the file would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a registry key from scratch like this:

```
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Cirrato'
$path = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\foo'

New-Item -Path $path -Force | Out-Null

Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'postInstallExecTimeout' -Value 30
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'ConfigApplyAllSettingsForModels' -Value ''
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'ConfigApplyAllSettingsForQueueNames' -Value ''
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'ConfigApplyPreferencesOnlyForQueueNames' -Value ''
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'OURestrictFailureCaption' -Value ''
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'OURestrictFailureText' -Value ''
```

The registry entries will normally be created with the appropriate type for the input value (`REG_DWORD` for integers, `REG_SZ` for strings). If not you can specify the type via the `-Type` parameter.